Troubleshooting the Android Emulator
android emulator out off bounds in android studio to get the parrlax effect or implementation Resolving "Out of Bounds" Issue in Android Emulator
Check Display Settings:
Ensure that your display settings (resolution and scaling) on your computer are correctly configured. Sometimes, high DPI settings can cause display issues.
Update Android Studio and Emulator:
Make sure you're using the latest version of Android Studio and the Android Emulator. Updates often fix bugs and improve compatibility.
Reset Emulator Configuration:
